# Receiving image using fastAPI: Store and load or just passing the handler around

Tags: python, file-handling

I am receiving images using fastAPI and I am passing that image around to other object and functions to do some processing. Do you think it will more efficient if I just store that image and load it when I need it, or should I just keep passing the image as it is?

My thought is that storing and loading image will be slow since it need access to the hard drive. But moving around the handler just look very messy, and since I am doing some preprocessing on the image as well when passing into different function, it become even more messy.

Comment: Difficult to tell without any code, any measure, any concrete performance objective. Consider doing some benchmarking. My guess would be that it is slower to store/reload. And you would have to pass the filepath around instead of the filehandle, so to me it does not change much. Have you considered loading your image content in memory to not have to pass the handle ?

Comment: @Lenormju Can you clarify you last point? Since I am not storing my image, I am assuming the image is already in the memory, but how did it save me from not have to pass the handle? I suppose what I am really curious about is how a server in real world will handle a file uploaded by the user if there is not needs for storing that information for the long term.

Comment: I thought that "moving around the handler just look very messy" meant that you had a file handle, but that was an error. The [FastAPI docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/) mentions that it is actually stored in-memory. Your question "Do you think it will more efficient" can not be answered without any code, you should do some benchmarking if you want to be sure, but my bet is on keeping it in-memory will be faster.

Comment: @Lenormju Make sense, thanks!